# ShortCut to open last closed file in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-juno

In Firefox we have <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close current tab  and  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd>  to open last closed tab.

Same in eclipse , we have <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>  for closing current file. But **is there any shortcut for opening last closed file?**

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Close a tab and hit the `left yellow arrow` in the `Eclipse menu bar` above or <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT</kbd> from keyboard, will open you  closed files in eclipse editor

Comment: Incorrect. This works only when you close active tab. Actually `Alt`+`Left` moves backward in the editor navigation history, i.e. returns to the **previous edit location**, that doesn't necessarily mean closed tab (just try to open 3 tabs, switch 2 times between 1st and 2nd tab, then close **inactive 3rd tab**, and press Alt+Left). Eclipse's bug tracker has corresponding ticket since 2008: [Open last closed tab](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=236240) - vote for it.

Comment: Victor is right. Alt+LEFT go to previous edit location as well as Alt+RIGHT go to forward.

Answer (score 16):

The last file to be edited is shown at the end of the File drop down menu.  Selecting it from that menu will re-open the file.  By default the 4 most recently edited files are shown.  The preferences page lets you change that number to no more than 15.  That's the best you can do.

Comment: where is the file drop down menu?

Comment: It depends on your OS.  It's the on the main toolbar that goes `Eclipse File Edit ... Window Help`

Comment: Actually it's in File -> Recent Files.